# Spring.net customer namespace parser

Tags: spring.net

I have a customer parser which looks like this:

```
[NamespaceParser(
Namespace = "http://mysite/schema/cache",
SchemaLocationAssemblyHint = typeof(CacheNamespaceParser ),
SchemaLocation = "/cache.xsd"
)
]
public class CacheNamespaceParser : NamespaceParserSupport
{
public override void Init()
{
RegisterObjectDefinitionParser("cache", new CacheParser ());
}
}


public class CacheParser : AbstractSimpleObjectDefinitionParser
{

protected override Type GetObjectType(XmlElement element)
{
return typeof(CacheDefinition);
}

protected override void DoParse(XmlElement element, ObjectDefinitionBuilder builder)
{

}

protected override bool ShouldGenerateIdAsFallback
{
get { return true; }
}
}
```

in the web config i have the following configuration....

```
<spring>
<parsers>
<parser type="Spring.Data.Config.DatabaseNamespaceParser, Spring.Data"/>
<parser type="App.Web.CacheNamespaceParser, WebApp" />
</parsers>
```

When I run the project I get the following error:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for spring/parsers: Invalid resource name. Name has to be in `'assembly:<assemblyName>/<namespace>/<resourceName>' format.`

I put a break point in the CacheNamespaceParser init method and it is called.

If I remove 
from the web config all is well!

Any ideas whats wrong

Comment: It appears that this exception is coming from the Spring.Core.IO
AssemblyResource constructor. Is this related to the attribute:


NamespaceParser(
Namespace = "http://mysite/schema/cache",
SchemaLocationAssemblyHint = typeof(CacheNamespaceParser ),
SchemaLocation = "/cache.xsd"
)

?

Comment: The resourceName passed to the above constructor

assembly://WebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null/cache.xsd" string

I seem to have resource name, an assembly name but no namespace name...

Answer (score 0):

Its look like attributes parameter SchemaLocation is wrong. Try something like this:

```
[NamespaceParser(
Namespace = "http://mysite/schema/cache",
SchemaLocationAssemblyHint = typeof(CacheNamespaceParser ),
SchemaLocation = "/YOUR_ASEMBLY_NAME/cache.xsd")]
```

It have to work if your cache.xsd is in the root of assembly.